# Desktop Duplication API Display Unsupported

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-engine, intel, nvidia

I've been trying to use [uDesktopDuplication](https://github.com/hecomi/uDesktopDuplication) by [hecomi](https://github.com/hecomi/) to project the connected Monitors inside Unity Editor (Unity Game Engine), his work was really interesting.

I should be contacting the developer to ask for help but then I considered posting here

Problem:
It seems that Desktop Duplication API is unsupported in Nvidia GPU's.

I've tried disabling Nvidia from my Device Manager to forcefully let unity use Intel HD / Also later tried setting Unity3D.exe to use Integrated Graphics in Nvidia Control Panel.

this works in my laptop with gtx 960m, but not in the one with gtx 1070.

Is it possible to keep using Nvidia and Project the monitors inside unity.
Is there any workaround for this problem. I'll be very grateful for any help.